# Qt Program crashes with another compiler

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with this part of my code? It crashes during execution.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
char * cstr = new char [ui->lineEdit->text().length()];
       string costam;
       costam=ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString();
       strcpy(cstr, costam.c_str()); <<<----TROUBLE LINE
       int z;
       z=costam.length();
       for(int n=0;n<z;n++){
            string wynik;
            wynik=konwersja(cstr[n]);
            mors(wynik);
            Sleep(300);
           }
   delete[] cstr;
   }
```

When I try to compile it with MinGW in Qt 5.0.1 everything is OK but with MSVC2010 in Qt 4.8.1 there is a warning:

> warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is wrong. This code compiles and there's nothing about QT here.

`strcpy` is deprecated because it's unsafe. Alternative is `strcpy_s`:

```
strcpy_s( cstr, ui->lineEdit->text().length() + 1, costam.c_str() );
```

Note that you should allocate `ui->lineEdit->text().length() + 1`, not `ui->lineEdit->text().length()`. That's the reason of crash, I guess.

BTW I see no reason to use `cstr` array in your code at all. As example:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    string costam;
    costam = ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString();
    for( size_t n = 0; n < costam.length(); n++ ) {
        string wynik;
        wynik = konwersja( costam[ n ] );
        mors( wynik );
        Sleep( 300 );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you change this line `strcpy(cstr, costam.c_str());` with `strcpy_s(cstr, costam.c_str());` try compiling again?

Also it shouldn't prevent compiling, MSVC2010 is just warning about an unsafe usage. You can also lower the warning level of [MSVC2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Because people are not very aware of security when programming C++, and Windows gets a bad rap because of it, Visual Studio "deprecated" several functions which are common causes of buffer overflows.  In this case you should be fine, and can probably just disable the warning by defining _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.  You may also find this issue with posix functions, too, in which case you would be able to disable those warnings with a separate #define.

Comment: That might get rid of the warning, but that won't fix a crash. I think your edit was a bit presumptuous. There was no room allocated for the null termination character. The program probably compiles if he doesn't have warnings-are-errors enabled and it very well may crash.

Comment: He didn't indicate a crash in the question, only the title.  In any case there's nothing about QT here at all.

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell you in the first post, program is running but when I try to click the button program has crashed

Comment: Then Slavik81 has your answer, I believe.

Comment: Maybe is there another way to replace strcpy(cstr, custom.c_str()) in another function which gives me char* on output?

Comment: @withorlo are you just trying to get a QString as a const char* ? Try qPrintable(ui->lineEdit->text()), or ui->lineEdit->text()->toUtf8()->constData(). If you want non-const, try QByteArray myText = ui->lineEdit->text()->toUtf8() then myText.data().  You can also use toLocal8Bit() or toLatin1() instead of toUtf8() if you just want old-style ASCII strings.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here.

The crash is because strcpy will write `length + 1` characters into the destination buffer, but your buffer is only of size `length`. The +1 is for the null termination character, which is not included in `length`.

The warning is because Microsoft believes its too easy to make mistakes using strcpy and discourages its use. As Joel mentioned, you could enable a define to prevent that warning. I would not recommend semihyagcioglu and Microsoft's suggestion of using strcpy_s, as it's not a portable solution.

I'd also like to note that while fixing those things will make your code compile and run without error, there are other questions. Like: why do you need the cstr variable in the first place? cstr[n] can probably be replaced with costam.data()[n]. Then the cstr variable won't need to exist at all. You won't need the new, delete or strcpy.